# Remote Server returned '550 5.1.10 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipientNotFound; Recipient not found by SMTP address lookup'

Tags: smtp, exchange-server, exchange-server-2016

I have an exchange server 2016 and I've created a user, say testuser1@exchangedomain.com

I followed the steps as told in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GN2mZ6qOWf8

I'm trying to send a mail from testuser1@exchangedomain.com in the exchange server to any outlook account in the outside world, for example, username@outlookdomain.com

But I'm unable to send a mail from testuser1 and I'm receiving this error on the exchange server
Remote Server returned '550 5.1.10 RESOLVER.ADR.RecipientNotFound; Recipient not found by SMTP address lookup'

Is it even possible to do so because both the domains are completely different or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The recipient email account is not found or doesnot exist. Even sending an email from Gmail gives "Address not found
Your message wasn't delivered to username@outlookdomain.com because the domain outlookdomain.com couldn't be found. Check for typos or unnecessary spaces and try again".

Answer (score 0):

From `[this article][1]`:

> Although the Recipient Filter agent is available on Mailbox servers,
> you shouldn't configure it. When recipient filtering on a Mailbox
> server detects one invalid or blocked recipient in a message that
> contains other valid recipients, the message is rejected. If you
> install the antispam agents on a Mailbox server, the Recipient Filter
> agent is enabled by default. However, it isn't configured to block any
> recipients. For more information, see [Enable antispam functionality
> on Mailbox servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/antispam-and-antimalware/antispam-protection/antispam-on-mailbox-servers?view=exchserver-2019).